# Таблица синуса и косинуса

Tags: c++, оптимизация

Ради оптимизации решил сделать табличку в которой будут лежать синусы и косинусы. Рисует почти как надо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

появляется какой-то пик. не могу понять почему и от куда он берется.

```
sincos::sincos(){
double step = 6.28318530717958647692 / 4096.0f;
sinTable = new float[4099];
cosTable = new float[4099];
int index = 0;
for (double i = 0; i < 6.28318530717958647692; i += step)
{
    sinTable[index] = std::sin(i);
    cosTable[index] = std::cos(i);
    index++;
}

float sincos::getSin(float val)
{
    val = fmod(val, 6.28318530717958647692);
    return sinTable[(int)(4096.0f * val / 6.28318530717958647692)];
}
float sincos::getCos(float val)
{
    val = fmod(val, 6.28318530717958647692);
    return cosTable[(int)(4096.0f * val / 6.28318530717958647692)];
}
```

Comment: какой стандарт для обработки чисел с плавающей запятой используется в вашем компиляторе?  IEEE 754?

Comment: а график чем строится?

Comment: Ну а вы сами посмотрите, на какое значение аргумента приходится неправильное значение функции. У вас же отладчик есть? Вам проще, чем нам догадываться методом пристального взгляда.

Comment: В таких случаях нужно давать минимальный самовоспроизводимый пример. Который можно скопировать себе, **сразу** скомпилировать и проверить.

Comment: Действительно нужен пример, и еще для sin и cos я бы использовал одну общую таблицу.

Comment: Как-то я пытался аналогичным образом оптимизировать и напоролся на то, что доступ к этим таблицам **медленнее**, чем считать `sincos` в том месте, где они требуются (я не ошибся, именно `sincos`, а не отдельно `sin` и `cos`). Вы попрофилируйте сначала..

Answer (score 2):

В вашей таблице нет никаких пиков - http://ideone.com/T4nigg

Так что разбирайтесь с рисованием...

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class SinCos
{
public:
    SinCos()
    {
        double step = 6.28318530717958647692 / 4096.0f;
        sinTable = new float[4099];
        cosTable = new float[4099];
        int index = 0;
        for (double i = 0; i < 6.28318530717958647692; i += step)
        {
            sinTable[index] = sin(i);
            cosTable[index] = cos(i);
            index++;
        }
        maxIdx = index;
    }

    float getSin(float val)
    {
        val = fmod(val, 6.28318530717958647692);
        return sinTable[(int)(4096.0f * val / 6.28318530717958647692)];
    }
    float getCos(float val)
    {
        val = fmod(val, 6.28318530717958647692);
        return cosTable[(int)(4096.0f * val / 6.28318530717958647692)];
    }

    float maxSinDelta();
    float maxCosDelta();

    float* sinTable;
    float* cosTable;
    int maxIdx;
};

float SinCos::maxCosDelta()
{
    float maxval = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < maxIdx; ++i)
    {
        float delta = fabs(cosTable[i] - cosTable[(i+1)%maxIdx]);
        if (maxval < delta) maxval = delta;
    }
    return maxval;
}

float SinCos::maxSinDelta()
{
    float maxval = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < maxIdx; ++i)
    {
        float delta = fabs(sinTable[i] - sinTable[(i+1)%maxIdx]);
        if (maxval < delta) maxval = delta;
    }
    return maxval;
}


int main()
{
    SinCos s;
    printf("MaxDelte sin = %f, cos = %f\n", s.maxSinDelta(), s.maxCosDelta());
}
```

Comment: Интересная проверка, спасибо. Как оказалось да, проблема была в рисовании. Туда посылали отрицательные значения :)